# Spring boot Liquibase classpath based migration files

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm unable to get liquibase migration working with Spring Boot when I'm deploying the app in a docker container. I have a fat jar which is extracted when the docker image is created.

I have a separate module where I keep my migration files. I am able to load the master.xml:

```
<includeAll path="classpath*:/changelog" relativeToChangelogFile="false" />
```

It then goes on and loads the rest of the resources. The problem is that `SpringResourceOpener.java` then extracts the real path from loaded resources which is still ok:

```
jar:file:/app/lib/database-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/changelog/001-categories-table.xml
```

But then does some path manipulations which ends up with:

```
lib/database-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/changelog/001-categories-table.xml
```

Which in turn is not a valid classpath path:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource 
[lib/database-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/changelog/001-categories-table.xml]
cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

I either need the `/changelog/001-categories-table.xml` (classpath) or `file:/app/lib/database-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/changelog/001-categories-table.xml` to be able to read the file. But it always ends up the incomplete path as above.

Is this a configuration issue or there is a way to tweak this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with manually referencing the change log files with include in `master.xml` rather than includeAll.

e.g.

```xml
<!--includeAll path="changelog" relativeToChangelogFile="false" /-->

<include file="changelog/001-table.xml" />
<include file="changelog/002-table.xml" />
<include file="changelog/003-table.xml" />
<include file="changelog/004-table.xml" />
```